# How to create a Video Player

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

I'm trying to create a simple video player with 3 buttons: play, stop and pause. My video will be from the raw folder or at a server url that I will upload it to. Do you have any tutorial on this in order to get some ideas? Also, I have created a media player with a song, but I think that this can't work for videos, right?

Comment: another way would be to add a flash video player in my project and just add my video inside it..

Comment: If you made it flash, you'll limit your product to those few phones that support flash.

Comment: another ready video player except from flash??

Comment: Look at your answers!  Those aren't flash!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a project sample in the SDK for the VideoView. You can attach a MediaController to it, which will show you play/pause stop and skip buttons. It's also on the developer website, [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html).

Answer (score 3):

this may be what you are looking for: http://davanum.wordpress.com/2009/12/04/android-%E2%80%93-videomusic-player-sample-take-2/

To make this more abstract, the [VideoView Widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) is what you need.